# Delete function in Laravel don't work anymore? SQL error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multithreading, laravel

I'm getting this error message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`Laravel`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`thread_id`) REFERENCES `threads` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `threads`
>   where `id` = 191)

Thats appears if i'm trying to delete a thread. I don't really understand why, cause the delete function was working all the time. I don't now how this mistake appears, but I can't imagine that there is something with my database. I allready had this error once, but the error was in my code, not in sql.

its about this here:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
         {!! Form::open(['action' => ['Test\\TestController@destroy', $thread->id], 'method' => 'delete',  'class' => 'blog-form']) !!}
         <button style="color:red; width: 80px; background: none; border: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</button>
         {!! Form::close() !!}
</ul>
```

Like I said, it was working all the time. I don't know where I did some changed but I can't find the mistake jet.

my route:

```
Route::delete('/delete/{id}', ['as' => 'destroy', 'uses' => 'Test\\TestController@destroy']);
```

and the delete function:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);
        $thread->delete();

        \Session::flash('flash_message', 'successfully deleted!');
        return redirect(action('Test\\TestController@startpage', [Auth::user()->id]));
    }
```

Thread -> comment realation:

```
 public function threadcomment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Thread\Comment', 'thread_id', 'id');
    }
```

Comment -> thread realation

```
public function commentthread()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Thread\Thread', 'thread_id', 'id');
    }
```

I also know to 100% I added a On Delete Cascade to my database.

Comment: Share your scopes and relationships as well

Comment: Could you also share your migrations files?

Comment: I think maybe there is something in my model. I will update my question with my comment and thread model

Comment: In your `commentthread` method: Shouldn't the foreign_key be `comment_id` instead of `thread_id`? Could you also post the result of `EXPLAIN threads` and `EXPLAIN comments` to that we see the structure of those tables?

Comment: solved the code :) thanks anyway :) the solution is in my question

Comment: Great and thanks for clarification :) Can you please mark this thread as solved?

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you have two tables, `threads` and `comments`. When deleting items from the thread table that are still linked with the `comments` table it gives you this error.

Can you show us your database layout? Are you using a pivot table?

If you are using a pivot table make sure your are adding `onDelete('cascade')`:

```
$table->foreign('thread_id')->references('id')->on('threads')->onDelete('cascade');
```

See the [Schema Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema) for details.

Comment: I have an On Delete Cascade in my database. If I'm looking at my db structure the On delete cascade is listed. Thats why I don't think its because of my database :/

Comment: solved the code :) thanks anyway :) the solution is in my question

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the OP)*.

The problem was the Laravel form. I needed to put the form::open and the form::close, around the dropdown tags. Ridiculous - thanks anyway.